# How can I look up a part number string with a range of subvalues?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to search a parts database for a part number with the following format: `aa-b-cc-dd-ee-ff` where `ee` is a number that can be +/- 2 of the original value.

For example: aa-b-cc-dd-**30**-ff should return part numbers that match:

- aa-b-cc-dd-**28**-ff
- aa-b-cc-dd-**29**-ff
- aa-b-cc-dd-**30**-ff
- aa-b-cc-dd-**31**-ff
- aa-b-cc-dd-**32**-ff

I know I can turn the string into an array using `explode('-', "aa-b-cc-dd-ee-ff")` and grab the `ee` value from there to make the 5 different values, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to accomplish this in a query using a range for the ee value:

`$products = Attribute::where('Part-Number', 'LIKE', '%' . {something here} . '%')->get();`

Comment: Are you trying to return products that match or just the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return all products that match.

```
$num = 30;
$range = range($num - 2, $num + 2);
$regexp = "^[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{1}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-(" . implode('|', $range) . ")-[[:digit:]]{2}";
$products = Attribute::whereRaw("Part-Number REGEXP '$regexp'")->get();
```